# Could [NSMutableArray array] return nil?

Tags: ios, memory, nsmutablearray

For example in low memory conditions. I'm reading third party code and I saw this

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

if (array != nil) {

    [array addObject:anObject];
}
```

I've never check this after creating an array that way nor `alloc+init` but now I'm in doubt.

Comment: I have seen that as well, not checking for nil would return an "unrecognized selector". I am confused about this too.

Comment: instead of **nil**, you can check `[array count] != 0` or `if (array)`

Comment: @hajder Messaging `nil` does **not** crash with `unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`.

Comment: @H2CO3 I recall that defining the array like [NSMutableArray array] yielded that error. If I can reproduce I will post a new question about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, it *could* return `nil`.

The probability of such a failure at that point is incredibly unlikely. Your app would probably crash or abort before a `nil` were returned. Consider it about as unlikely as `malloc` returning `NULL`.

My implementations have used checked object creation for years - I cannot remember ever seeing  `[NSMutableArray array]` return `nil` in that time in development/testing.

Note that this answer is specific to `[NSMutableArray array]`, not any/every initializer/constructor in existence. `[NSMutableArray array]` is nearly the most 'consistent' class of initializer/constructor in this regard because there is no reason for it to fail under normal circumstances.

Comment: Yet not checking `malloc() != NULL` is always frowned upon, unlike this. *Why that?*

Comment: @H2CO3 good question :) minimum operating environment has virtual memory and a good chunk of memory, ability for the system to kill other tasks or your own, and the number of abstraction layers between the implementation and the client?

Comment: yeah, maybe. But I would be *sooo* happy if I didn't have to write my own `safe_malloc() { return malloc() || abort() }` every time... (especially in my latest project, where `malloc()` is a bottleneck, and I've literally never encountered it returning `NULL`...)

Comment: @H2CO3 at least you're using `malloc` in that case, and have the ability to implement your own allocators if needed. a good reason to check malloc is that there is an additional variable -- the size parameter.

Comment: That's meaningful. Yes, one cannot definitely alloc an arbitrary-sized memory chunk. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. An object instantiation that fails for any reason should return nil unless the method states otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of that `nil` check. `[NSMutableArray array]` rarely returns nil. And if it gets to a (memory) situation that this method returns `nil`, your app is as good as killed.

The only possible case for that method fails is in tight memory constrained situations. iOS will never let memory goes down that much, without doing sufficient actions like memory warnings and purging background apps before.

Also in your example code, even if array is `nil`, you don't need to check for nil, since method calls on `nil` are ignored. I am only talking about your example code.

Comment: Could you link me a resource/doc to check that?

Comment: From my iOs development experience, if OS doesn't have enough memory to allocate an object, the app wouldn't run. Memory warning and background app purging will be already done to avoid such a situation. In any case, that nil check is not doing any help in such a memory constrained situation.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` can be backed by a mutable `CFArray` instance. `CFArrays` are created by [`__CFArrayInit()`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744/CFArray.c), which can return `NULL`. I think saying `+[NSMutableArray array]` never returns `nil` is unwarranted: it could if the allocator fails (which might not be just due to running out of memory).